# Selecting row corresponding to date range in an inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in one table (Table A) that looks like:

```
id      datestart        dateend         department
1       2008-01-01       9999-12-31      fmcg
2       2010-02-01       2011-04-09      sales
.       .                .               .
.       .                .               .
```

With millions of rows and 9999-12-31 means current date. I have another table (Table B) that looks like:

```
yearmonth      id 
2010-01-01     1  
2010-01-01     2  
2010-02-01     1  
2010-02-01     2  
.              . 
.              .
```

id in Table A can have multiple rows, for instance, id 2 was in sales but there is another row that looks like:

```
id      datestart        dateend         department
2       2011-04-10       9999-12-31      fmcg
```

Which means they moved to fmcg after sales (no overlap of dates)
What I'm trying to do is add another column in Table B which shows where the employee was working at yearmonth:

```
yearmonth      id        department
2010-01-01     1         fmcg
2010-01-01     2         NULL
2010-02-01     1         fmcg
2010-02-01     2         sales
.              . 
.              .
2011-05-01     1         fmcg
2015-05-01     2         fmcg
```

Apologies I am unable to post the exact code I've used as it's on my work computer and I'm currently using a different computer but it looks similar to:

```
select a.*
     , case when b.dateend = '9999-12-31' then b.department
       when a.yearmonth < b.dateend then b.department else b.department end as department
from table_a a
inner join table_b b on a.id = b.id
(apologies if missing crucial bits, am going by memory)
```

I know this code doesn't work as I get something similar to:

```
yearmonth      id        department
2010-01-01     1         fmcg
2010-01-01     2         NULL
2010-02-01     1         fmcg
2010-02-01     2         sales
2010-02-01     2         fmcg
.              . 
.              .
2011-05-01     1         fmcg
2015-05-01     2         fmcg
2015-05-01     2         sales
```

but I'm having troubles understanding what will work. If you could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: what do you wanna show if something moved in the middle of month , like for id 2 for month April

Comment: It would be a sort of stocktake at the start of the month so as of the 2010-04-01, id 2 is still in sales but as of 2010-05-01, they are a part of fmcg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.YearMonth, ApplyResult.Department FROM TableB B
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT A.Department FROM TableA A 
        WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND B.YearMonth BETWEEN A.DateStart AND A.DateEnd
) ApplyResult
```

Or this:

```
SELECT B.ID, B.YearMonth, A.Department FROM TableB B
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A On A.ID = B.ID AND B.YearMonth BETWEEN A.DateStart AND A.DateEnd
```

TableA:

```
ID  DateStart   DateEnd     Department
1   2008-01-01  9999-12-31   DepA
2   2010-02-01  2010-03-09   DepA
2   2010-03-10  9999-12-31   DepB
```

TableB:

```
ID  YearMonth
1   2010-01-01
2   2010-01-01
1   2010-02-01
2   2010-02-01
1   2010-03-01
2   2010-03-01
1   2010-04-01
2   2010-04-01
```

Output:

```
ID  YearMonth   Department
1   2010-01-01   DepA
2   2010-01-01   NULL
1   2010-02-01   DepA
2   2010-02-01   DepA
1   2010-03-01   DepA
2   2010-03-01   DepA
1   2010-04-01   DepA
2   2010-04-01   DepB
```

Comment: YES!! Oh my, thank you so much this is exactly what I am after.

Comment: @Linda T,  I added a second query to the answer. It seems better. Please check it too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the date condition to the `on` clause:

```
select a.*, b.department 
from table_a a inner join
     table_b b
     on a.id = b.id and
        b.yearmonth between a.datestart and a.dateend
```